# Allow SE app to share external links from in-app browser (Chrome Custom Tab)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, sharing

Many times question or answer has relevant and informative external links which when tapped, opens in an in-app browser (Chrome Custom Tab). Currently not able to retain when we need. How about "share"ing the page? At least I can send myself as an email.

Adding below link for illustration:

http://www.devtopics.com/101-more-great-computer-quotes/

[image: Click external link]

[image: Click menu on top right]

[image: A direct share here would be nice]

Comment: You mean copying the link?

Comment: Yes, in a way. But actually after you reading the page and felt "Great, let me save the page for future reference" from the page. Just noticed "Open in Chrome" option there, which is one step away from what I want. Still could be a good feature to have.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. A "read later" button? Sharing with who?

Comment: You click a link, takes you to an article at some site in an in-app browser. How to share this article?

Comment: Could you not just share the question/answer containing the link to the interesting article to an app that handled saving interesting links like Pocket, or Inbox etc.?

Comment: Yes, there are more than one work around available now in the app. This direct method can be"nice to have", if not "must have" :)

Comment: Weird. When I click external link I'm asked to choose browser. What version you have?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, StackExchange version 1.0.85 running on Android 5.1

Comment: Can you please take screenshots and post them here? One with an external link showing, then another showing what you get when tapping it. I understand what you mean, but the question gathered four close votes as Unclear What You're Asking, so better explain.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Done. Added screen shots :)

Comment: So weird. I get this when tapping the link: http://i.imgur.com/RNXzp6U.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard the screenshot is about Chrome Custom Tab, when Chrome is set as default app to open link from SE app.

Comment: My slightly related suggestion: [Add a way to see where links go in Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269461/241919)

Comment: Well, if that is part of Chrome, SE can't do anything with it, so this request is technically impossible. (i.e. will be declined.)